# How can I find and replace cells containing #N/A in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet

I used a `VLOOKUP` function on some cells, and got lots of `#N/A` among some results. I then later copy/pasted them *as values* to another sheet. So now I have a column with a few numbers and several `#N/A`s.

I simply want to textually replace all `#N/A`s with zero. But if I use the *Edit -> Find and Replace...* menu, and then put `#N/A` in the "Find:" field, it doesn't find anything. The same happens if I search `#N/A` in the Find bar (via Ctrl+F).

[image: screenshot of LibreOffice Calc showing some example data and the Find bar illustrating "search key not found"]

How can I just quickly find and replace these values? I don't want to modify the formulas I use; other spreadsheet editors do allow searching for such values without issues.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

**In the *Find and Replace* dialog, in *Search In:*, choose *Formulas*. Then LibreOffice Calc will find occurrences of #N/A.**

[image: Screenshot of LibreOffice Calc, dialog Find and Replace, highlighting the "Search In" option, which must be set to "Formulas" for the search to find occurrences of #N/A.]

##### Detailed explanation

It turns out that Libreoffice has a very *odd* definition of what is a *Value*, or at least lacks consistency when displaying it in the *Paste Special* dialog. Even if you choose *Values Only*:

[image: Screenshot of the Paste Special dialog of LibreOffice Calc, highlighting the selected Preset "Values Only"]

Then, when you try to find the `#N/A` values in the Find and Replace dialog, they will *not* be found if you let the "Search in:" option as "Values":

[image: Screenshot of Find and Replace dialog of LibreOffice Calc, highlighting the selected "Search in:" option, by default as "Values"]

**You have to change this option to *Formulas*.**

If you do so, entering `#N/A` will let LibreOffice Calc find the cells where it has been pasted to (but it will *not* find those still containing the `VLOOKUP` formula, even if its result leads to `#N/A`).

FWIW, my LibreOffice version is 7.8.5.2.